# I want to print out an itemized receipt with total cost

Tags: python

I am a beginner in programming and I'm working on the projects in *Automate the Boring Stuff with Python,* In the book there is a project to create a sandwich, then return the total cost. I want to add to my program by providing an itemized receipt. For example, if I put in an order for 1 sandwich with wheat and chicken and 3 sandwiches with white and turkey, the receipt should show something like this (I will format it better when I figure it out):

1 sandwich ---3.5
wheat, chicken

3 sandwich ---10.5.
white, turkey

Total       ---     14.00

My challenge is storing the different sandwich orders into different variables and printing them out at the end.

My code below:

```
menu = {
     'wheat': 1.5, 'white': 1, 'sourdough': 2,
     'chicken': 2, 'turkey': 2.5, 'ham': 2, 'tofu': 3,
     'cheddar': 0.5, 'mozzarella': 0.25, 'american': 0.5,
     'mayo': 0.25, 'mustard': 0.25, 'lettuce': 0.5, 'tomato': 0.5
       }

total = 0.0
subtotal = 0.0

while True:
    order = {}
    print('What bread would you like?')
    order['bread'] = pyip.inputChoice(['wheat', 'white', 'sourdough'])
    print('How about for your protein?')
    order['protein'] = pyip.inputChoice(['chicken', 'turkey', 'ham', 'tofu'])
    wantCheese = pyip.inputYesNo('Would you like cheese on the sandwich?')
    if wantCheese == 'yes':
        order['cheese'] = pyip.inputChoice(['cheddar', 'mozzarella', 'american'])
    wantToppings = pyip.inputYesNo('Would you like to add extra toppings?')
    if wantToppings == 'yes':
        while True:
            order['side'] = pyip.inputChoice(['mayo', 'mustard', 'lettuce', 'tomato'])
            anotherTopping = pyip.inputYesNo('Would you like another topping?')
            if anotherTopping == 'no':
                break
    orderNumber = pyip.inputInt('How many of those sandwiches would you like? ', min = 1)
    for choice in order:
        if order[choice] in menu.keys():
            subtotal += menu[order[choice]]
    total *= orderNumber
    total += subtotal
    subtotal = 0
    anotherOrder = pyip.inputYesNo('Would you like to order another sandwich?')
    if anotherOrder == 'no':
        break

print(total)
```

Comment: So, just create an `orders` list, and do `orders.append( order )` at the end of your loop.  When you exit the loop, you can iterate over the `orders` and print the receipt.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, can you advise on how to turn each order into a tuple, then append that to the orders list?

Comment: Using a dictionary is sufficient. By the way - when you ask, "[w]ould you like another topping", if the person says yes then that second choice will overwrite the first choice.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @tajimari does my answer answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the following as you see fit. FYI, while coding this up I had "let's get this to work" in mind as opposed to "let's make this as efficient as possible". Moreover, you should format the receipt however you like.

Importantly, I created a list called `orders` just before the `while` that will be used to store orders. The form of the elements of `orders` will be 3-tuples where the first element of the 3-tuple records `orderNumber`, the third element records the subtotal, and the second element is an `order` dictionary, just as in your original code, except `order["side"]` will be a `list` as this allows for multiple additional toppings to be added. For the sample output below, `orders` is

```
[(2, {'bread': 'wheat', 'protein': 'chicken', 'cheese': 'cheddar', 'side': ['mustard', 'lettuce']}, 9.5), (1, {'bread': 'sourdough', 'protein': 'turkey', 'side': []}, 4.5)]
```

As you can see, there are 2 orders of `'wheat', 'chicken', 'cheddar', 'mustard', 'lettuce'` (subtotal 9.5) and 1 order of `'sourdough', 'turkey'` (subtotal 4.5).

I hope this helps. Any questions please let me know.

```
import pyinputplus as pyip

menu = {'wheat': 1.5, 'white': 1, 'sourdough': 2,
        'chicken': 2, 'turkey': 2.5, 'ham': 2, 'tofu': 3,
        'cheddar': 0.5, 'mozzarella': 0.25, 'american': 0.5,
        'mayo': 0.25, 'mustard': 0.25, 'lettuce': 0.5, 'tomato': 0.5
        }

orders = []
while True:
    order = {}

    # choose bread
    print("What bread would you like?")
    order['bread'] = pyip.inputChoice(['wheat', 'white', 'sourdough'])

    # choose protein
    print("How about for your protein?")
    order['protein'] = pyip.inputChoice(['chicken', 'turkey', 'ham', 'tofu'])

    # choose cheese
    wantCheese = pyip.inputYesNo("Would you like cheese on the sandwich?")
    if wantCheese == 'yes':
        order['cheese'] = pyip.inputChoice(['cheddar', 'mozzarella', 'american'])

    # choose extra toppings
    order["side"] = []
    wantToppings = pyip.inputYesNo("Would you like to add extra toppings?")
    if wantToppings == 'yes':
        while True:
            order["side"].append(pyip.inputChoice(
                ['mayo', 'mustard', 'lettuce', 'tomato']))
            anotherTopping = pyip.inputYesNo("Would you like another topping?")
            if anotherTopping == 'no':
                break

    # order number
    orderNumber = pyip.inputInt(
        "How many of those sandwiches would you like?", min = 1)

    # subtotal
    subtotal = sum(menu[order[key]] for key in order if key != 'side')
    subtotal += sum(menu[j] for j in order['side'])
    subtotal *= orderNumber 

    # add 3-tuple to orders list
    orders.append((orderNumber, order, subtotal))

    # another order?
    anotherOrder = pyip.inputYesNo("Would you like to order another sandwich?")
    if anotherOrder == 'no':
        break

# add subtotals to form total
total = sum(order[2] for order in orders)

# print orders (for programmer use)
print(f"\nOrders: {orders}")

# print receipt
print(f"\nReceipt\n")
for order in orders:
    print(f"{order[0]} sandwich ---{order[2]}")
    print("    ", end = "")
    for key in order[1]:
        if isinstance(order[1][key], list):
            for x in order[1][key]:
                print(x, end = ", ")
        else:
            print(order[1][key], end = ", ")
    print("\n")
print(f"Total --- {total}")
```

Sample output:

```
Receipt

2 sandwich ---9.5
    wheat, chicken, cheddar, mustard, lettuce, 

1 sandwich ---4.5
    sourdough, turkey, 

Total --- 14.0
```